# Is it possible to create a custom CodeIgniter app in Expression Engine 2.x

Tags: php, codeigniter-2, expressionengine

I have a quick question. But before I ask I will give a brief background of our current situation.

Right now we have a site that is running EE 1.7.0, which manages all of our front-end marketing pages, members, forum, etc (basic CMS stuff). Once a member logs in they are directed to our main application that is running CodeInigter 1.7.2. We've created custom EE extensions and database tables so the two systems can share sessions (going from EE to CI and vice versa without having to re-login every time). Our main application is quite extensive and is running CI's Modular Extensions ([WIKI](https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc/wiki/Home)).

My question is this. We are looking to upgrade to EE 2.x. If we do this, is it possible to use the same CI instance for both? Can we install HMVC into CI that EE uses? Or do we have to do what we are doing now, but in this case have two separate instances of CI?

I have found a potential ["hack"](http://paramore.is/think/entry/harnessing-the-power-of-codeigniter-in-expressionengine-2.0/) that might help but I don't want to waste my time if its not even possible or will be more headaches than its worth.

I would love to use the same instance if possible. I think our app is way to complex to build a module within EE 2.x.

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would probably be better off using a separate CI instance. The CI version that is bundled with EE is quite outdated, and you could quite likely run into issues with it which you can't solve by upgrading to the latest CI version.

I would keep your app separate, and simply write your own code to use the EE session in your app (use EE to handle your login/registration pages). EE 2.x completely overrides the CI session class anyway so you will probably still need custom code for this.

Keeping the app decoupled means far fewer things to go wrong, and I expect will result in fewer headaches for you.

Comment: Yeah, thats what I figured. Thanks for the information. Looks like 2 CI installs it is then! :)